# The outer ring of the path color only changed a little bit

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, stroke, topojson

I was doing d3 visualisation work. And I want to change the path stroke color when mouseover.
But I met one problem. The inner ring of the path stroke changed color successfully; however, the outer ring just changed a little bit. As I am new to stackoverflow, I didn't get enough reputation to post a picture.
For example, refer to link below:

[link](https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/cityscience.j839negl/page.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2l0eXNjaWVuY2UiLCJhIjoialBPOTRkNCJ9.kS1rIozWXdXJIVNI_g6xTQ#9/-37.9312/144.9728)

When it's mouseover on one ring. Only the inner ring changed stroke color, the outer ring only changed a little bit.
I use this code:

```
d3.select(this).style("stroke","blue");
```

And my code is correct because I tried the on the example [topojson file](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590), the stroke changed successfully.

BTW, I covert the original shape file into topojson file like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON destination.json source.shp         <- to change from shape to json

topojson -p xxx -o destination.topo.json  source.json  <- to change from json to topojson
```

I have no idea why the stroke of the outer ring does not change?

Is it related to the shape file? Maybe something wrong with the shape file? I guess?

Thanks in advance!

Below is my code for this issue. I

```
d3.json("js/all_land.json", function(error, topology) {
      svg.selectAll("path")
       .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.all_land).features)
       .transition()
       .duration(1000)
       .attr("d", path);

svg.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", function(d) {  

     d3.select(this).style("stroke","blue");
     //d3.select(this).attr("fill", "lightblue");

})
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it's difficult to say, but  what could be the issue it that the edge of the outer ring is underneath the inner ring.  To get your desired effect you could change the fill colour instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I edit my post and add my code there. Would you help me to take a look at the code if you got time? Thanks.

Comment: We need more details in order to be able to provide an answer. Could you please create a fiddle or share the full code?